# Из php в javascript

Tags: json, php, javascript

Не получается перекинуть массив из php в javascript

```
    <?php
    $arr = array("one", "two", "three", "four");
    $json = json_encode($arr); 
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var name = "<?php echo $json; ?>";
document.write(name.join(", "));
</script>
```

в браузере ничего не выводится... хром ругается на эту строку в исходном коде:

var name = "["one","two","three","four"]";
т.е. функция json_encode похоже вообще ничего не сделала

вопрос, естественно в том, как сделать что бы работало?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите кавычки вовсе, а то данные воспринимаются как одна строка ;)

```
var name = <?php echo $json; ?>;
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас и внешние и внутренние кавычки двойные.

Comment: внешние это какие? или какие внутренние?

Comment: а я понял, элементы в таких же ковычках

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй написать

```
var name = '<?php echo $json; ?>';
```

Т.е. взять в одинарные кавычки.